# Node.js process.kill is causing an unsuccessful process exit (1)

Tags: node.js, process, signals, posix, sigterm

I am new to node.js and following the [node.js documentation about process signals](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-exit-from-a-nodejs-program) i've written the below code

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hi!");
});

const server = app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server ready"));

process.on("SIGTERM", () => {
  console.log("Handler started");
  server.close(() => {
    console.log("Process terminated");
  });
});

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i === 5) {
    process.kill(process.pid, "SIGTERM");
  } else {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

but after running this app in the terminal the output (`node app.js`) is the following:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

The handler didn't run

After debugging the process is exiting with code = 1 when running `process.kill`.

How to debug this to know the exact cause ? I couldn't print the error with a try catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the windows os is not POSIX so it doesn't use unix signals.

The best thing to do is to either use the windows subsystem for linux (WSL2) to develop on a unix environment using windows or develop node js application on unix os

Answer (score 1):

> Why "Handler started" and "Process terminated" are not printed to the
> console ?

When I am running the below script, I am getting things printed on console. I think you should run the below script and test it:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hi!')
})

const server = app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server ready'))

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  server.close(() => {
    console.log('Process terminated')
  })
});

for(let i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
  if(i === 5) {
      process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGTERM')
  }else{
      console.log(i)
  }
}
```

Results after running the above script:

```
AV:newTest11 apoorvachikara$ node test.js 
0
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
Server ready
Process terminated
AV:newTest11 apoorvachikara$
```

It seems there are some issues with the script you are running.

Comment: Yes but why listening on a port is required for this to work ? It should enter the handler in the question code

Comment: Process will only be available when you start the server. Once you get the process, you can send different signals.

Comment: Turned out the error is in the process.kill method. Updated the question. Even when listening to a server the error is still hapenning

Comment: What node version are you using? Because running the same code on my machine, produces the same o/p as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: version 16.13.0. (running on windows 10)

Comment: When you run the above script, what is the o/p you are getting on your machine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239917/discussion-between-eeah-and-apoorva-chikara).